# WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken doesn't work when app uses proxy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I need to have an Android app where I use a proxy URL to connect to our MFP 8.0 server. When I make an android build without proxy pointing directly to the MFP server the app registers in the server and I am able to see the push notification in my device.

But when using a proxy in the config.xml the app is able to reach the server but returns an error on the step where I do `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken`.

This is the error:
errorCode:"201"
errorMsg:"Created"
responseText:"{"server_version":"8.0.2017081900"}"
status:201
statusText:"Created"

Comment: There is hardly any details about what you have done. You do obtainAccessToken() for which scope? And what do you do within the obtainAccessToken() ? Register the device ? 201 is not an error code. It is the status code for "Created" . Did you verify if the registration happened ? Or you already had a registration and was it updated? Provide more details

Comment: I obtain scope for a scope variable I created in the server called 'push.mobileclient'. And once that's a success I call MFPPush.registerDevice.

I verified in the devices list of the MFP server, the device is not getting registered since MFPPush.registerDevice is not called.

Comment: Can you perhaps take a wireshark network capture and upload it. Looks like your proxy is either blocking or modifying some data to/from the MobileFirst server. A wireshark will give a correct picture.

Comment: If the device is not in Devices list, this means even the ObtainAccessToken call has not succeeded. You call might not be reaching the server. Verify network traffic to see where it is getting blocked